# Not same value in the same variable

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am running into issues putting many items in DynamoDB

I am using this lib : https://github.com/baseprime/dynamodb

I get the error : `The conditional request failed`

Here is my code

```
const addInput = input => {
  console.log('input', input);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Input.create(
      {
        id: input.id,
        playlist: input.playlist
      },
      {
        overwrite: false
      },
      (err, inputRes) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('input2', input);
          console.log('inputRes', inputRes);
          console.log('err', err);
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(inputRes.get('id'));
      }
    );
  });
};
```

And my logs shows for the same lambda request id

```
input { id: 1567787730645,
playlist: 2010}

input2 { id: 1567786871913,
playlist: 80}

inputRes undefined

err { ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed ..
```

How can the input variables have different values ?

Comment: let's do a little experiment: add the following line `input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));` at the beginning of your function (just above the `console.log('input', input);` line). then run the code at let me know if the log has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
const addInput = input => {
    const data = { id: input.id, playlist: input.playlist };
    console.log('input', input);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Input.create(data,
        {
            overwrite: false
        },
        (err, inputRes) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('input2', input);
                console.log('inputRes', inputRes);
                console.log('err', err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(inputRes.get('id'));
        });
    });
};
```

### Exaplanation

You make the `Input.create()` inside the `Promise`'s function. This function is not invoked when the promise is created. Instead, it is invoked at some unknown time in the future. This means that after `addInput()` any changes made to the object passed to `addInput()` will affect the `id`, `playlist` values passed to `Input.create()`. By copying these values at the beginning of `addInput()`, and not inside the `Promise`'s function, you fix this problem.

Comment: I’ll try this and let you know. Thanks a lot !